# PHP file/directory stat-related functions do not work on mounted CIFS

Tags: php, linux, mount, stat, cifs

I am using PHP on a 32 bit Linux for walking through a mounted remote filesystem (CIFS) and I have noticed that Unix's stat-related functions do not work (`stat()`, `filemtime()`, `is_dir()`, and so on).

This is starting point:

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/cifs-mount-point
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o user="user",password="password" //example.local/share /mnt/cifs-mount-point
```

And these are some tests:

```
<?php

stat('/mnt/cifs-mount-point/directory');   // This will rise a Warning and return false
is_dir('/mnt/cifs-mount-point/directory'); // Will return false
```

I have checked the same in Bash and it works as expected:

```
$ stat /mnt/cifs-mount-point
$ if [ -d /mnt/cifs-mount-point ] ; then echo "is dir"; fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stat()` may not work on mounted CIFS' in 32 bit systems if you do not specify the option `noserverino` when mounting. E.g:

```
mount -t cifs -o user="user",password="password",noserverino //example.local/share /mnt/cifs-mount-point
```

Other functions based on `stat()` data such as file time functions and `is_dir()` are affected the same way.

This happens because if you do not specify the option `noserverino` the remote inode may be 64 bit-based and thus the local system cannot handle it.